# Low German/Plattdütsch word usage detail

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-structure, low-german

Is one or the other of these phrases more accurate in terms of meaning? The meaning of the phrase in English is: *"a pleasure to be seen."*

> **Een Pläseer to't ansehn.**

or

> **Een Vergnögen to't ansehn.**

How to forms of this phrase in Plattdütsch? The intention is that it is spoken to multiple people.

Comment: I don't recognise the form of Platt you're using here, but I'd say neither convey your English phrase.  What I think both of the Platt expressions say is "A pleasure to behold" (something nice to look at), whereas your English phrase to me expresses "someone who takes joy out of being seen".

Comment: Thanks, tink. That is helpful and you are right about the meaning I am after here. If you want to offer other suggestions, I would be grateful.

Comment: Sorry, that's it from me =} ... what Region of Germany is that Platt from?

Comment: I'm not sure. I was getting help from someone else and they suggested it. Perhaps it is only Hochdeutsch.

Comment: Heh. It definitely isn't Hochdeutsch :}

Comment: Well, goes to show I really need the help here. Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: @tink "dat Vergnögen" as well as "dat Pläseer" are used in East Frisian Low German.

Answer (score 2):

*Plattdeutsch* is not a single language/dialect, but rather a group of german dialects with some similarities in writing, vocabulary and pronunciation. Unlike *Hochdeutsch* however, there is no standard way of spelling, writing, pronouncing or even which vocabulary to use. This can even differ notably from one village to the next.

Your best approach would be to look into the specific regional version of *Platt* you are after. Mixing several variations can work, if your possible sources do not yield enough examples, but be careful about vocabularies:

While some versions of *Platt* are notably influenced by French:

> Pläseer (platt) <=> plaisir (french)

others are far closer to *Hochdeutsch*

> Vergnögen (platt) <=> Vergnügen (high-german)

The suggested sentences overall seem a bit odd because of the form

> to't ansehn

*to't* seems to be a contraction of *to et* (also *tau et*, *tau het*, again no fixed way of writing/ pronouncing) which means *zu dem*, *zu den* (some variations of *Platt* do not care much about grammatical case or gender)

Following that witch the supposed verb *ansehn* (*look [at something]*) does not make a lot of sense. A possibility here would be a transformation into a substantive: *Ansehn* which means

1. *[the] look [of something]*, compare: (high-german) *Angesicht*, [the] look [of someone, esp. face]
2. *[the process of] looking [at something/someone]*
3. *[the] reputation [of someone]*

**Conclusion:** Both version by themselves can pass as *Platt*, but if context (esp. regional context) matters, it gets really difficult to say without additional information.

My additional suggestion would be:

> Aan Vergnüje antusehn / antausihn

which is a take on a variation of *Harzer Platt*. 
[Link: Discussion of these variations (in german)](http://www.harz-geschichte.de/page-band02/mundarten-harz.htm)

There is a [*High-german* to *Platt* online dictionary](http://www.deutsch-plattdeutsch.de/) which your source may have used. However it contains no information which locations the words are used in.

There are [Stories in *Platt*](http://www.de-plattsnackers.de/cms/Inhalt-zeigeGeschichten/) available online (Region around Schortens, Lower Saxony), so you may want read up on some of them to get a feeling for the dialect.

Comment: Thank you very much fer-rum. I see this is more interesting and complex the more I learn. I appreciate your time and thorough response. I will keep cross-checking with my other sources and try to get to the closest regional dialect I can figure. The deeper meaning behind "to be seen" is more broadly: to be witnessed, to be accepted, to be acknowledged. Perhaps there are other words in Platt that may better fit this interpretation besides a more literal attempt to translate "seen."

Comment: Platt varies from town to town noticably. There are huge differences in pronounciation and vocabulary but not much in grammar. Grammar is much closer to Dutch Language than to standard German.